# Spring boot Hibernate not persisting nested entities

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jhipster

I have a table 'skills' and a table 'answers' (I know the should be singular). A skill has a relationship with an answer as in it can have multiple of them:

Skill entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "skills", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set<Answers> answers = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "answer")
private String answer;

@Max(value = 1)
@Column(name = "weight")
private Integer weight;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@NotNull
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "answers", allowSetters = true)
private Skills skills;
```

When I create a new skill using the following data:

```
{
   "name":"Hello",
   "shorthand":"EE",
   "answers":[
      {
         "answer":"answer 1",
         "weight":1
      },
      {
         "answer":"answer 2",
         "weight":2
      },
      {
         "answer":"answer 3",
         "weight":3
      },
      {
         "answer":"answer 4",
         "weight":4
      },
      {
         "answer":"answer 5",
         "weight":5
      }
   ]
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
  "id": 1255,
  "name": "Hello",
  "shorthand": "EE",
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "answer": "answer 1",
      "weight": 1,
      "skills": null
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "answer": "answer 2",
      "weight": 2,
      "skills": null
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "answer": "answer 3",
      "weight": 3,
      "skills": null
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "answer": "answer 4",
      "weight": 4,
      "skills": null
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "answer": "answer 5",
      "weight": 5,
      "skills": null
    }
  ],
}
```

As you can see the ID for the skill was generated as it's a new entity but this is not happening for the answers, an id of null is returned for each of them + they are not persisted in the database. What am I doing wrong, any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify [cascade](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()) attribute in `@OneToMany`.

The example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "skills", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to be helpful but I get an error at the moment:

ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=skills, rootBeanClass=class be.project.domain.Answers, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}

Comment: That's a separate thing and in this case we need to see how your entities are being populated in service (probably something wrong with the use of hibernate sessions/`@Transactional` etc.)

Comment: I am sorry @amseager,  I passed an id of value 0 for the answers that caused the previous error, fixed that + I updated the comment. I am getting another error now, it seems to be related to the ManyToOne skills within the answers entity. Is this related to hibernate trying to persist the answer before persisting the skill failing the NonNull, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This can be fixed by setting `skills` field while creating `Answer` objects. So, you'll have smth like this: `Answers newAnswer = new Answers; .... newAnswer.setSkills(skill); ... skill.getAnswers().add(newAnswer);`

Comment: I am trying something like this:

        skills.getAnswers().forEach(answers -> answers.setSkills(skills));
        List<Answers> answers = answersRepository.saveAll(skills.getAnswers());
        skills.setAnswers(new HashSet<>(answers));
        Skills result = skillsRepository.save(skills);

But it results in a 'Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation'

Comment: You don't need to save answers entities separately - just save the root entity (skills), and all answers will be saved as well because of cascading:  `skills.getAnswers().forEach(answers -> answers.setSkills(skills)); Skills result = skillsRepository.save(skills); `

Comment: + I also added @JoinColumn(name = "skills_id") on the ManyToOne as it was missing.